# How to change the row height for only the last cell in a tableview?

Tags: objective-c

In my table view I had more than 200 rows and Im managing then by keeping loadmoreresults in last cell to display only 40 rows per page.when the user clicks on the load more results 40 more cells is displayed.I changed the row height of loadmoreresults cell as different from other. The problem is when there is no more results the height for other cell is effected with the height of the loadmoreresults cell I dont want to sffect the last row height to other rows.

The code I written as:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
ZohoAppDelegate* appDelegate = (ZohoAppDelegate*) [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

int maxResults = [appDelegate.invoiceMaxValues intValue];
int noOfResults = [invoiceArray count] ;
if (noOfResults != 0 )
{   
    if (maxResults > noOfResults)
    {
        noOfResults++;
        rowCount = noOfResults;
    }
}
return noOfResults;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row == (rowCount -1))
{
    return 50;
}
return 80;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"MasterViewIdentifier"] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    UIView* elementView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,312,480)];
    elementView.tag = 0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:elementView];
    [elementView release];
}
UIView* elementView  = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:0];
for(UIView* subView in elementView.subviews)
{
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
}

UIImageView* imaeView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 78)];
if(indexPath.row == (rowCount-1))
{
    elementView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.92578125 green:0.92578125 blue:0.92578125 alpha:1];
}
else
{
    imaeView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"estimatecellbg.png" ];
}
[elementView addSubview:imaeView];
[imaeView release];
    return cell;
  }
```

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == (rowCount -1) && moreResults)
    {
        return 50;
    }
    return 80;
}
```